# Find duplicate objects by a user defined set of fields

Tags: java

my goal is to find duplicates in list of approximately 500000 objects and more. But it should be possible to define what a duplicate is at runtime. Simply but, it should be possible to find duplicates by a (changing) set of user defined fields of those objects.

#### My approach

- create a decorator class for every field
- overwrite equal and hash methods
- create the desired objects (maybe just the fields color, height out of color, height, width, weight)
- find duplicates (not the problem here)

But is this a good approach? I have the feeling that is way too much boilerplate. Is there something more simple?

Restrictions: No SQL.

Comment: This site's more for specific technical help than recommendations/code review.  But: I don't get what the decorator's for.  You're going to redefine equals and hashCode at _runtime_?  That sounds a bad idea.  I'd just make a `Comparator` based on the fields the user requested, and check if the `Comparator` compared them to a `0` result.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ perhaps may be a better place for this question then?

Comment: Sounds like a hashmap keyed on a combined set of attributes, with counts.. Then filter to ones where count > 1. But with that volume I'd hate to think of the time it would take to identify - maybe maintain the hashmap as the objects are created/updated/deleted.

Comment: It makes sense to me for implementing a builder pattern and then compare objects based on the comparator?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about this some more, so I thought I'd make my comment-suggestion into an actual answer.

I would just create a `BiPredicate<T, T>` which was concerned with the fields requested (at runtime) and would return `true` if they were equal with regards to those fields, and `false` otherwise.

For example, say you had the following type:

```
public class YourType {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    private final int hatSize;
    // Constructors and getters omitted...
}
```

and you wanted to find duplicates ignoring `hatSize`, then you could write something like:

```
public BiPredicate<YourType, YourType> makeChecker(
        final Collection<Function<YourType, ?>> fieldGetters) {
    // 'first' and 'second' are the two 'YourType' instances
    // to be compared
    return (first, second) -> {
        // Iterate over all the field getters
        for (final Function<YourType, ?> fieldGetter : fieldGetters) {
           // Retrieve the field values from each object
           final Object firstsField = fieldGetter.apply(first);
           final Object secondsField = fieldGetter.apply(second);

           // If they're not equal, break early
           if (!Objects.equals(firstsField, secondsField)) {
               return false;
           } 
        }
        // All of the requested properties were equal
        return true;
    };
}
```

and invoke it with something like:

```
makeChecker(Arrays.asList(YourType::getName, YourType::getAge));
```

You can then do any normal 'remove duplicates' approach across the collection, comparing them using the returned `BiPredicate`'s `test` method.